# How to edit accounts & sync settings for a specific account

Tags: android

Under the 'Accounts & Sync' settings graphical OS menu, there are listings of user-configured Google accounts.

Please could someone point me in the right direction to programmatically change the sync settings associated with one of these accounts?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Those settings use the new `AccountManager` APIs.  Here's some [sample code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html) that shows how to add a new account.  I'd assume that you'd want to get the credentials of one of the existing accounts and simply modify the data.

Unfortunately, I haven't had a chance to try out those APIs yet.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe [`ContentResolver#setIsSyncable()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#setIsSyncable(android.accounts.Account, java.lang.String, int)) can do what you want.

Perhaps would be better to fire the [android.provider.Settings.ACCOUNT_SYNC_SETTINGS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_SYNC_SETTINGS) intent with either the EXTRA_AUTHORITIES extra set to `["google.com"]`, or possibly put the extra named `"account"` as the Account object you got from AccountManager. Then your user can turn their sync on or off for themselves.

Answer (score 1):

ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(account, authority, true/false): sets whether or not the provider is synced when it receives a network tickle.

Comment: I went through the Android SDK source code because this method puzzled me due to its weird documentation and the actual effect on my device. First of all "network tickles" are a proprietary Google thing which cannot be used by other app developers. I assume you'd have to implement a socket connection or push notification listener to trigger a sync. Second of all, deep down in the hierarchy of method calls of this method, the synchronization is just *enabled* for an account (take a look at SyncStorageEngine.java -> setSyncAutomatically). I think that method's documentation needs an update.